# ERROR in ./server.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main.bundle' in ... @ ./server.ts 16:9-45

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I followed the angular universal guide (https://angular.io/guide/universal)

When I execute:

```
npm run build:universal
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR in ./server.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main.bundle' in ...  @ ./server.ts 16:9-45
```

---

```
npm run build:client-and-server-bundles
```

works fine but

```
npm run webpack:server
```

fails

**Question:** Is it normal, that no dist folder is created when I execute the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-render‌​ing](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering) now it works

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: Link has been fixed.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who comes across this. In Angular 6, 'bundle' no longer appears in the filename. Check your server.ts file against this version: https://angular.io/guide/universal

For example, this line used to include "main.bundle":

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to change path inside file **tsconfig.server.json**

**From**

```
 "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
```

**TO**

```
   "files": [
       "main.server.ts",
        "../server.ts"
    ],
```

Other configuration should match with

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Answer (score 0):

One way you can have a relative path like this `../dist/server/main.bundle`

Second way to give absolute path use `require(join(process.cwd(), 'dist/server/main.bundle'))`